# Prove that $(-1)x = -x$

Tags: vector-spaces

My question is a proof in a vector-spaces chapter in an undergraduate book. I have tried using the existence of additive identity but that hasn't worked.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x$ is any vector in a vector space $V$, then

$0=0x=(1-1)x=1x+(-1)x=x+(-1)x$

which follows that $(-1)x=-x$

---

**Note:**  For $0=0x$

$0x=(0+0)x=0x+0x$ adding $-0x$ both side we get $0x=0$

Answer (score 1):

Since\begin{align}x+(-1)\times x&=1\times x+(-1)\times x\\&=\bigl((1+(-1)\bigr)\times x\\&=0\times x\\&=0,\end{align}you have that $(-1)\times x=-x$. Of course, now you have to prove that $0\times x=0$.